# Display Settings Window from MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

from within a MapFragment I'd like to display some kind of settings window. What would be the best way to do that? 
Replace the fragment? Create some kind of overlaying view? AlertDialog?

How would I best implement it?

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I would put the button in the ActionBar if your app has that. The settings page, or what you woul call it, would be a PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Put the settings in a diaglog fragment activated from button in the actionbar have an interface so you can update the map in background.

See this live in my app

Button in action bar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Process the button click

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int x = item.getItemId();
    switch (x) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        showSettingsDialog();
         return true;
```

do something useful show the fragment.

```
private void showSettingsDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    MapSettings editSettingsDialog = new MapSettings();
    editSettingsDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}
```

The complete mapsettings class.

```
public class MapSettings extends DialogFragment implements
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

    public static final String MAP_TYPE = "com.gosylvester.bestrides.settings.maptype";
BestRidesSettingsDialogListener activity;
SharedPreferences sharedpref;

public interface BestRidesSettingsDialogListener {
    void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // the activity may be null if this is called without implementing the
     // BestRidesSettingsDialogListener (The settings object saves the
    // setting so the
    // call back may not be needed.

     activity = (BestRidesSettingsDialogListener) getActivity();

     getDialog().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map_settings, container);
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    // initialize to the shared preferences value
    rg.clearCheck();

 ... homemade glue to get the initial setting.      
GoPreferences.getInt(getActivity(),MAP_TYPE,GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    RadioButton rb = null;

     switch (x) {
    case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID:
         rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RDOHybrid);
        rb.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL:
        rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RDORoad);
        rb.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE:
        rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RDOSatelite);
        rb.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN:
        rb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RDOTerrain);
        rb.setChecked(true);
        break;
    }
    // set the listener after setting up
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return view;
}   

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int mapType = 0;
    switch (checkId) {
    case R.id.RDORoad:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOHybrid:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOSatelite:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
        break;
    case R.id.RDOTerrain:
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
        break;
    }
    // run the activity onchange
    // if the activity is null there is no listener to take action on the
    // settings
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.onMapSettingsChange(mapType);
    }

    // save the settings


}
```

impliment the interface on your map activity so the map can be changed from the dialog fragment.

```
public class KmlReader extends ActionBarActivity implements
    BestRidesSettingsDialogListener, SnapshotReadyCallback,
    OnMapLoadedCallback {



@Override
public void onMapSettingsChange(int mapType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMapType(mapType);
    }
}
```

Good Luck
Danny117